# Duplicate Action names in same namespace .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm quite inexperienced with .NET MVC and as I looked my problem up, all the solutions concerning it were situations where people tried to use same controller name in different namespaces. I've a situation with duplicate controller names in same namespace and I'm wondering if there's a very simple solution that I can't seem to find.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(AddedItem model, ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {

        _insertProductService.InsertData(model.Name, model.Author, model.Description, files);
        ModelState.Clear();
        ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Item has been added!";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(AddedCategory model, ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {

        _insertCategoryService.InsertData(model.Name, model.Author, files);
        ModelState.Clear();
        ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Category has been added!";
        return View();
    }
```

I get the following error:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied

I've two forms in partial views that are called from Insert page. What is the best way to "force" application to choose the fitting IActionResult?
I think ActionConstraints might be the solution, however I struggle to understand them. In case I'm right about ActionConstraints, could someone please provide me a simple example that I could adjust in my solution?

insert.cshtml below as suggested:

```
 @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Add new";
    }
    @section Scripts2 {
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    }
    <h2 class="page-header">@ViewData["Title"].</h2>
    <h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#product">Product</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#category">Category</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="product" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/ProductFormPartial.cshtml")
        </div>
        <div id="category" class="tab-pane fade">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/CategoryFormPartial.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not create 2 actions: InsertProduct and InsertCategory?

Comment: You can't have two of the same named Actions in a controller using the same request method (HttpPost) as MVC routing will not try to interpret which action to use based off of the form data alone. You can customise this however it's avoidable by using different action names.

Comment: Insert.cshtml has tab-pills to select form and forms are displayed using "@await Html.PartialAsync(......)" so when I try to change action names to InsertProduct and InsertCategory, nothing happens. Did I misunderstand your point? @Alexan

Comment: post your Insert.cshtml

Comment: @Alexan posted insert.cshtml as suggested

Comment: I found a clunky solution. I can pass both form's parameters to same Action and compare what parameters have value of null. Based on that I can make a conclusion which form sent the data and choose the correct steps. However I wish there's a better solution for me.